# React Native Logout inside a DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I want to navigate back from DrawerNav to Login. Using alert('Alert') inside the function is OK.

I have a StackNavigator with Login and DrawerNav

```
const MyStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login : { screen : Login },
  DrawerNav : { screen : DrawerNav }
  }, {
    navigationOptions : { header : false }
  }
);
```

From Login i can navigate to my main screen DrawerNav using

```
_login = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerNav');
}
```

Inside the DrawerNav is a DrawerNavigator (obviously)

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    ... screens ...
  }, {
    initialRouteName : '',
    contentComponent : CustomContent,
    drawerOpenRoute : 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute : 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute : 'DrawerToggle'
  }
);

const CustomContent = (props) => (
    <View>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={ this._logout }>
        <Text style={ styles.logout }>Logout</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
)
```

As you can see, the logout is not part of the menu but inside the Drawer

```
_logout = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
}
```

This gives me an error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as well. anybody able to help?

Answer (score 1):

As you are quite deep in your navigation stack wouldn't it make sense to use the `popToTop` function?

In the same file make sure that you define your `_logout` function as your `CustomContent`, then you could do something like the following:

1. Update the function call by passing `props` to them
2. Update `_logout` to use `popToTop()`

Here is how my code would look.

```
_logout = (props) => {
  props.navigation.popToTop();
}

const CustomContent = (props) => (
    <View>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={ () => this._logout(props) }>
        <Text style={ styles.logout }>Logout</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
)
```

You will want to pass the `props` to the function as that will contain your `navigation` prop and allow you to make calls on your navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The `this` in `this._logout` is meant for referencing a `CustomContent` instance, but since `CustomContent` is a functional component (which doesn't have instances), any `this` reference shouldn't be valid but is not throwing an error due to [a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18942).

### Solution

Change

```
onPress={this._logout}
```

to

```
onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
```

Comment: you can see i have edited problem its the same problem as previous problem

Comment: @ArgusMalware that looks like a completely different problem (with a different error message).

Comment: You would have to create a new question as your edits would probably not be approved since they change the nature of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your customComponent to class component from functional.Like..

```
class CustomContent extends Component {
  _logout = () => {
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      key: null,
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this._logout}
        >
          <Text style={styles.logout}>Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE:* [Best practice to implement auth screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) is by using [switch navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html). If you're supposed not to use it for some reason, the following stuffs could help.

**1:** As @Asrith K S answered, change your functional component to class component and write `_logout` as class function, where `this.props` would have `navigation`

(or)

**2:** write navigate action as [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19159927/8359363).

```react
const CustomContent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={ () => props.navigation.navigate("Login") }>
      <Text style={ styles.logout }>Logout</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
)
```